# Python couchdb script consuming too much memory (getting KILLED)

Tags: python, couchdb

I'm processing a CouchDB view that has over 10 million rows returned. Is there a way to iterate over the rows that will "clean up" memory after I've processed a row?

For example, in django you can use queryset.iterator() to prevent queryset caching which helps greatly with memory consumption.

This is basically what I'm doing:

```
couch = couchdb.Server(url)
couch.resource.credentials = (username, password)
db = couch[database_name]
result = db.view('xxx/xxx', None, stale='update_after', reduce='false')
total = 0
for row in result.rows:
    total += row['value'].num
```

My actual code is more complicated than this so please don't suggest using a reduce in CouchDB.

Comment: Which CouchDB library are you using? https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=couchdb&submit=search

Comment: @BigBlueHat pycouchdb

Comment: You can either use a library that is based on an event-based JSON parser such as [json-streamer](https://github.com/kashifrazzaqui/json-streamer) or [iJSON](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson) (similarly to SAX vs DOM in the XML world) or call the view with paging options (see [`limit` and `skip`](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/views.html?highlight=skip+limit)).